# Rails 4 Nested Resources Error with 3 models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, nested-resources

```
Error: ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound Couldn't find Option with 'id'=
```

This is happening when I add a link to the options `show.html.erb` to get all the registrations for that option. In order to get the event id and the option id, I'm adding the following to the show method in the OptionsController:

```
@event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
@option = Option.find(params[:option_id])
```

This is the link I'm adding to the `show.html.erb` file:

```
link_to "Registrations", event_option_registrations_path(@option)
```

This is how my 3 models look: Event, option and registrations

`event.rb`:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :options, dependent: :destroy
end
```

`option.rb`:

```
class Option < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :event
  has_many :registrations
end
```

`routes.rb`:

```
  resources :events do
    resources :options do
      resources :registrations
    end
```

Route for Registrations:

event_option_registrations_path    `/events/:event_id/options/:option_id/registrations(.:format)` 
registrations#index

Comment: When is the error happening? Where are your `params` coming from? From what little you posted it looks like 'params[:option_id]` is nil at the time of execution.Post the web server logs so we can see what is happening before and after the error.

Comment: thanks for you reply.
**before adding : @option = Option.find(params[:option_id])**
Started GET "/events/1/options/25" for ::1 at 2015-11-20 21:55:03 -0500 Processing by OptionsController#show as HTML Parameters: {"event_id"=>"1", "id"=>"25"}
  Option Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "options".* FROM "options" WHERE "options"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 25]]
  Event Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "events".* FROM "events" WHERE "events"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Event Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "events".* FROM "events" WHERE "events"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]

Comment: Rendered options/show.html.erb within layouts/application (1.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 74ms (Views: 73.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

Comment: **After:**
Started GET "/events/1/options/25" for ::1 at 2015-11-20 21:55:25 -0500
Processing by OptionsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"event_id"=>"1", "id"=>"25"}
  Option Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "options".* FROM "options" WHERE "options"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 25]]
  Event Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "events".* FROM "events" WHERE "events"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Option Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "options".* FROM "options" WHERE "options"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", nil]]
Completed 404 Not Found in 15ms (ActiveRecord: 1.0ms)

Comment: @Asan you need to change `@option = Option.find(params[:option_id])` to: `@option = Option.find(params[:id])`. Look at my answer's edit part in the bottom. Try that, and let us know.

Comment: Just a point of usage. Don't paste logs or large pieces of code into comments, edit your answer to include them. They are usually impossible to read from comments.

Comment: @Beartech Ok I'll edit the post from now on. Sorry, I'm new here. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Error: ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound Couldn't find Option with 'id'=
```

This error message is saying that, it can't find the option with id = `nil` when you do this:

```
@option = Option.find(params[:option_id])
```

which means, your `params[:option_id]` is `nil` in this case.

You should put a print statement in your controller like this:

```
def your_action
  # these are for debugging
  puts params.inspect
  puts params[:option_id]
  @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
  @option = Option.find(params[:option_id])
end
```

Then you will be able to see what you are getting inside your `params` hash. Then, you can grab the correct attribute and then do the rest of the work. Hope this helps you debug the issue and solve your problem.

## Update

change this:

```
@option = Option.find(params[:option_id])
```

To:

```
@option = Option.find(params[:id])
```

Because, in your params hash, you don't have a `option_id` key, but you have a `id` key which refers to the id of the `option`.

Comment: That worked, In order to make to link work I changed it to this:
<%= link_to "Registrate",event_option_registrations_path(@event,@option) %>

Thanks!